# An easy puzzle to solve

Tags: word, geography

Which country's name cannot be written using only the first letter of any other country on the planet?

For clarification, the first letters of the countries below spell GREECE.

Germany

Romania

Equador

Estonia

Canada

Eritre

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, ask a new question. Don't edit over your old question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like I must be missing something.

Is it:

> MEXICO? I don't think any country starts with X.

But then you also cannot get:

> LUXEMBOURG

Also:

> Formally, no country begins with W, so RWANDA is also out.

Comment: I think there's going to be a few of these! Like rot13(YHKRZOBHET gbb - be nal jvgu n 'J', fb OBGFJNAN, rFJNGVAV, FJVGMREYNAQ, ...)

Comment: (Great minds...!)

Comment: @Stiv: I watched The Kardashians, and sadly not-so-great minds do also think alike :-)

Comment: @Stiv  or Jeremy Dover. There is a country whose Capital's anagram was the capital of the same country for a long time. Guess?

Comment: @DrD rot13(WNCNA: sbezre pncvgny jnf XLBGB, pheerag pncvgny vf GBXLB)

Comment: You know your countries @JeremyDover